# Creating tables in SQL Server 2005 master DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am adding a monitoring script to check the size of my DB files so I can deliver a weekly report which shows each files size and how much it grew over the last week.  In order to get the growth, I was simply going to log a record into a table each week with each DB's size, then compare to the previous week's results.  The only trick is where to keep that table.  What are the trade-offs in using the master DB instead of just creating a new DB to hold these logs? (I'm assuming there will be other monitors we will add in the future)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is that `master` is not calibrated for additional load: it is not installed on IO system with proper capacity planning, is hard to move around to new IO location,  it's maintenance plan takes backups and log backups are  as frequent as needed for a very low volume of activity, its initial size and growth rate are planned as if no changes are expected. Another reason against it is that many troubleshooting scenarios you would want a copy of the database to inspect, but you'd have to attach a new `master` to your instance. These are the main reasons why adding objects to `master` is discouraged. Also many admins understandably prefer an application to use it's own database so it can be properly accounted for, and ultimately easily uninstalled.

Similar problems exist for `msdb`, but if push comes to shove it would be better to store app data in `msdb` rather than `master` since the former is an ordinary database (despite widespread believe that is system, is actually not).

Answer (score 2):

The Master DB is a system database that belongs to SQL Server. It should not be used for any other purposes. Create your own DB to hold your logs.

Answer (score 1):

I would refrain from putting anything in master, it could be overwritten/recreated on an upgrade.

I have put a DBA only ServerInfo database on each server for uses like this, as well as any application specific environmental things (things that differ between prod and test and dev).

Answer (score 1):

You should add a separat database for the logging. It is not garanteed that the master database is not breaking the next patch of sql server if you leave your objects in there.

And microsoft itself does advise you to not do it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx